# Can you change function names a in while loop - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, while-loop

I was wondering if you can change function names while in a while loop? For example, if I had an X amount of functions called function1, function2, function3, functionX, could I execute the function with the loop number tracker? Something like this:

```
def function1():
    do this

def function2():
    do that

def function3():
    do something

def...

i = 1

while i <= X:
    function(i)
    i += 1
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to make it work?

EDIT:
I'm new to python so I wanted to try to make a simple project rather than watching tutorials. I'm, trying to make a "hangman" game. The loop is needed to draw the hanger and the parts depending on the right or wrong answer. Each function has the code to draw the next step. There is an if statement in the loop, if the user answers the wrong letter then function(i) should be used (depending on the amount of times the user has missed).

Thank you!

Comment: This is almost certainly an XY problem. If you explained _why_ you wanted to do this, someone might be able to suggest the correct pattern

Comment: Also, "loop number tracker" sounds like you should be using a `for` loop, not a `while`.

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow and to python. will edit my question so it's more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of functions named `function0 - functionN`? The best solution would be to simply *put these functions in a container, like a `list`* then iterate over that list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - yep storing the functions in a list did it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all of them in a list and call them by index. Then you don't need to worry about what they are called, just the **order** that they should be called, which seems to be the most important thing for you.

```py
def function1():
    print('function 1')


def function2():
    print('function 2')


def function3():
    print('function 3')

functions = [function1, function2, function3]


i = 1

while i <= 3:

    functions[i-1]() #note the () to call the function

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
eval("function1()")
To run function1 so you can just change the string every time the for loop runs.

Comment: While this would technically work, using `eval` is almost always a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: if you could, should you?

Second thing: yes, you can, but probably shouldn't.

```py
def function1():
    return 1

def function2():
    return 2

# ...

i, num = 1, 2 # num can be as much as you have defined functions
while i < num + 1:
    print(globals()[f'function{i}']())
    i += 1

# out
# 1
# 2
```

Maybe you should take a look into [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

As stated in [@Alon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14498451/alon)'s answer, you can also you `eval`. But keep in mind that both solutions are a result of **bad design** and I repeat: **being able is not a good reason to do it**.

Comment: Using `globals()` is _also_ bad design

Comment: Yep, that's why I wrote "keep in mind that **both** solutions are bad design" as in "the solution I gave **and** using `eval` come from bad design. The thing is: using similar name functions that return similar results is bad design in itself.

Comment: Fair, you are right. Would there be a "best practices for answering questions" for stackoverflow? I only read the "how to ask questions".

Comment: Hahaha, yes, I understand. I am studying engineering so most of the times people come for solutions, not for learning how to approach and better solve a problem. I should change this mindset when accessing stackoverflow.

Comment: From what I am gathering, people just post things without thinking much about it, which is pretty sad. How was it in the early days?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223482/discussion-between-felipe-whitaker-and-roganjosh).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign functions to variables in python. This variable can then be overwritten with another function. An example of this can be seen here:

```py
def fn1(x):
   return x

def fn2(x):
   return x*2


test = fn1
print(test(4)) # prints 4

test = fn2
print(test(4)) # prints 8
```

Applying this to your example we can create an array containing all your functions, which you iterate over the indexes or a dictionary where the key is your id and the value is your function:

```py
def function1(args):
    do this

def function2(args):
    do that

def function3(args):
    do something

myfunctions = {'1':function1,'2':function2, etc...}

i = 1
while i <= len(myfunctions):
    myfunctions[str(i)](args)
    i += 1
```

or using the list method:

```py
def function1(args):
    do this

def function2(args):
    do that

def function3(args):
    do something

myfunctions = [function1,function2, etc...]

for i in range(myfunctions):
    myfunctions[i](args)
```

I would say that if you are running all the functions 0:X the list method is simpler, but if you have data telling you which one to run a key-value dictionary would be easier.

In an ideal world, you would have one function that does different things based on its input.

**Note on eval** As per the other answers, the use of eval would also work, however in the interest of efficiency and good coding practice it is better avoided if possible!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when one function follows another, I would do something like this:

```
def function1():
    do this
    return function2

def function2():
    do that
    return function3

def function3():
    do something
    return fail?

def...

function = function1
i = 1
while i <= X:
    function = function()
    i += 1
```

where there is always a `function` called, but it changes each iteration to the next one.

Firstly, I wanted to suggest the same as others with writing functions in lists or dictionaries and iterating through them. But I think returning the next function is better for your case.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the other answers with lists and that works, but I will also try out your solution